# Reloading static resources in Grails 3

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

Assuming an `index.html` file under `src/main/resources/public/` folder in a Grails 3 application, how does one update it and have the changes immediately available without restarting the application?

With Grails 2, any changes to the `web-app` folder where available on browser reload, so I am assuming a caching mechanism has been introduced.

Comment: why don't you put it into `grails-app/assets`?

Comment: what should happen once one puts it there?

Comment: as far as I understand, the (static) files from `assets` folder are delivered by `asset-pipeline` (ex-asset plugin, afaik), and caching / reloading etc is supported out-of-box

Comment: not using a view layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by moving statics from `src/main/resources/public/` to `src/main/webapp` folder.

Comment: I am not able to see my static assets regardless of which of these two directories they are located in. If my app context is "/app" and I have a file at test/index.html under webapp, would you expect me to see that page at localhost:8080/app/test/ ?

Comment: Please try adding this config to application.yml:

`grails:
    resources:
        pattern: '/**'
`

Comment: Thanks! I actually just figured it out...however for some reason I still have to type index.html after /app/test/

Comment: Yes, because it is a static. But you can render it with a controller with any URL: https://github.com/tolyo/angular-qotd/blob/master/core/grails-app/controllers/com/example/IndexController.groovy

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I'm not following you. I have a completely single page web app that is being built with webpack into the src/main/webapp folder to be served by grails....Is there a setting I can change with Grails so that /app/test/ renders the index.html without typing index.html?

Comment: Create an `AppController` with `test` method that returns an `index.html` resource. The link above does exactly what you want. Its a working demo btw.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130257/discussion-between-anatoly-ostrovsky-and-alex-white).

Comment: Is this still working on 3.2.11? I have tried with src/main/resources/public/ and src/main/webapp.

Comment: Haven't tried it, but given how the front-end oriented profiles (react, angular) are structured, I would say the established practice is to use a separate build pipeline.